# Which is the best PHP ORM for codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, frameworks

Which would be the best ORM for the codeigniter framework. I saw some similar questions but it was too old and the link didn't work. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### DataMapper

> An Object Relational Mapper written in PHP for CodeIgniter. It is designed to map your Database tables into easy to work with objects, fully aware of the relationships between each other.

Website: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/

### Gas ORM

> A lightweight and easy-to-use ORM for CodeIgniter. Gas was built specifically for CodeIgniter app. It uses CodeIgniter Database packages, a powerful DBAL which support numerous DB drivers. Gas ORM provide a set of methods that will map your database tables and its relationship, into accessible object.

Website: https://github.com/toopay/gas-orm

### Doctrine

Website: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/

**NOTE**: You must do some workaround to integrate this with CI, try [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html).

**EDIT**: Doctrine, [integrating with CodeIgniter](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html) (working URL). *This might not work for all CodeIgniter versions and may require slight adjustments.*

Comment: https://github.com/fabiocmazzo/rabbit-orm is latest as of writing this.

Answer (score 5):

I've used Doctrine a number of times with CI and I love it.  As I understand it there are two different ways to integrate CI with it, you can either install it as a plugin or use hooks.

Reference:

http://web.archive.org/web/20160126131627/http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html