# How to use AND in JOIN the Codeigniter way

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How can I transform this MySQL query into Codeigniter query?

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN user_category_subscriptions ON 
    user_category_subscriptions.category_id = categories.category_id
    and user_category_subscriptions.user_id =1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the AND part inside Codeigniter's join()

```
$query = $this->db  ->select('t1.*')
                    ->join('user_category_subscriptions t2', 't1.category_id =t2.category_id AND t2.user_id =1','left')
                    ->get('categories t1');
return ($query->num_rows())?$query->result():false;
```

with this line after the query you can double-check if the query was generated correctly:

`echo $this->db->last_query();die;`

more about **CI 2.x** [Active Record Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) and alternatively **CI 3.x** [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-class)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/examples.html):

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT name, title, email FROM my_table');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->email;
}

echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows();
```

#### ORM:

If you would like to use an ORM, you could follow the advice given on this [StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22816869/8592146)