# Codeigniter: Nested Array from DB

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to pull customer orders from my database in an array. My database structure has an orders table, then an order_items table that joins on the order ID fields of both tables.

```
public function getUserOrders($id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('orders');
    $this->db->join('order_items', 'order_items.order_id = orders.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('products', 'products.id = order_items.product_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('cust_id', $id);
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
  }
```

I want my array structure to be nested, so that in each order array there is a nested array of products for that order, can I achieve this in my model above?

Comment: While the ORM answer is valid that solution might be overkill if you don't need to restructure datasets on a regular basis. It is not that hard to restructure result using simple loops. If you could share an example result set from the above a query an accurate answer may be possible.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter can’t do nested arrays easily out of the box from a DB request. I would consider using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). [A quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+orm) suggests a few, but rather helpfully [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816018/which-is-the-best-php-orm-for-codeigniter) might be the best to flick through.